# Duplicating javascript combotree

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have 100 combotree's on a page and it's taking forever to load since each new combotree that is made, the loadData function has to run. The data is always the same so is there a way to make this run only once to speed the page up?

Here is the documentation for a [combotree](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=)

`for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $("#tree" + i).combotree("loadData", data);
}`

Can I run the combotree function once then copy to the other elements?

Comment: `combotree`? What's that?

Comment: Sorry @Cerbrus it's part of jquery EasyUI. I've added a link to documentation.